# Bjarne Stroustrup Book - Vector and For loop - won't work

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I'm having difficulties with a particular piece of code I'm learning from "Programming Principles And Practice Using C++".

I can't get an output from a loop refering to a vector. Am using std_lib_facilities and stdafx because the book and MVS told me so.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"


int main()
{
    vector<string>words;
    for(string temp; cin>>temp; )
        words.push_back(temp);
    cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << '\n';
}
```

This will produce nothing. I'll get the prompt, type in some words, then enter, then nothing.

Tried some variations I got here and from other websites as well, such as:

```
//here i tried the libraries the guy used in his code
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a series of words followed by End-of-File: ";
    vector<string> words;
    string word;
    string disliked = "Broccoli";

    while (cin >> word)
        words.push_back(word);

    cout << "\nNumber of words: " << words.size() << endl;

      // cycle through all strings in vector
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
    {
      if (words[i] != disliked)
          cout << words[i] << endl;
      else
          cout << "BLEEP!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Still nothing.

After trying some things, by elimination I'm pretty certain the problem is with the loop-to-vector communication, because all of these work fine:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string>words = { "hi" };
    words.push_back("hello");
    cout << words[1] << "\n"; // this will print hello

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size();++i) {
         cout << words[i] << "\n"; // this will print out all elements 
                                   // inside vector words, ( hi, hello)
         }

    cout << words.size();// this will print out number 2

    for (string temp; cin >> temp;) {
         words.push_back(temp);
        }

    cout << words.size();// this won't do anything after i type in some 
                         // words; shouldn't it increase the size of the 
                         // vector?
}
```

Neither will this alone:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string>words = { "hi" };
    for (string temp; cin >> temp;) {
        words.push_back(temp);
        }
    cout << words.size();
}
```

What am I missing, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code works properly. https://wandbox.org/permlink/GYEiNuoMGABLZJpD Try `std::cout << std::endl` instead of `"\n"` to flush stdout.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. Where in the code should I put this?

Comment: You need to signal an end-of-file to get out of the `for` loop.  On Windows at the start of a line type `^Z` then enter.  On Linux type `^D` instead.  Or use a file and redirection for input and EOF will be be triggered at the actual end of the file.

Comment: I tried the ^Z typing, but still nothing. I don't know how to do redirection. I'm using the book to learn C++. Sorry. But thanks for your help.

Comment: By `^Z` I mean `Ctrl-Z` in case that's not understood.

Comment: Redirection: `my-compiled-program.exe < file-with-words-in-it.txt`

Comment: This is not a C++ question, it's more likely a Windows question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Input the strings and when done press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>) if on Windows or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> if on Linux. When you do that the `cin>>temp;` condition inside your `for` loop will evaluate to false and your program will exit the loop.

Comment: Yes, I did that. But nothing happened. It only writes ^Z. Literally pressing Ctrl and then Z writes off ^Z after the last string I type in. Maybe it has to do with the notebook keyboard? I'm on Windows 7, using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @JohnnyJohnny The answer addresses your first block of code.

Comment: Expanding on that:  `cin>>temp` returns `cin` itself. In turn, `cin` evaluates to `false` when either there was an error or the end of input has been reached. So unless you redirect your program's input, it reads from your keyboard, which has no end (you can always type more things), and never returns false. To artificially mark the end of input, your prompt/terminal program usually has a special sequence such as Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z which it recognizes, suppresses and acts upon by closing the "keyboard file" of the currently running program.

Comment: @JohnnyJohnny: Make sure you type Ctrl-Z on a new line.

Comment: I think you need to press enter after (and before) the ^Z. Until you press the final enter, you can still undo the ^Z

Comment: Yes! Pressing enter before and after worked. Thank you very much. But why did it worked  here wandbox.org/permlink/GYEiNuoMGABLZJpD without this? BTW, if I had enough points, I'd upvote the answer.

Comment: That's why my comment said: "at the start of a line type ^Z then enter". I'll admit that it's an easy to overlook detail.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, I overlooked it. That's why, now that I have enough points, I'm giving you your spoils as points. Thank you very much. Selecting the best answer.

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, it is not necessary to use the `std_lib_facilities.h`.    That is just something used in the book to avoid having every example in the book regularly include a set of standard headers, or to correct for non-standard behaviours between compilers.     It is also a header that that does `using namespace std` - you will find numerous examples (both on SO and the wider internet) explaining why it is VERY poor practice to have `using namespace std` in a header file.

Second, it is not necessary to use `stdafx.h` either.   That is something generated by Microsoft IDE, and provides a means of speeding up compilation in large projects, because of how it causes the compiler to work with precompiled headers.    If you only expect to use Microsoft compilers, then feel free to fill your boots and use this one.   However, it is not standard C++, may (depending on IDE and project settings) include windows specific headers that will not work with non-Microsoft compilers, and in forums will probably discourage people who use other compilers from helping you - since they will have good reason to assume your code uses Microsoft-specific extensions, which will mean they probably can't help you.

The first sample of code can be rewritten, in standard C++ (without use of either header above) as

```
 #include <vector>    // for std::vector
 #include <string>    // for std::string
 #include <iostream>   // std::cout and other I/O facilities

 int main()
 {
      std::vector<std::string> words;
      for(std::string temp; std::cin >> temp; )
           words.push_back(temp);
      std::cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << '\n';
 }
```

Before you get excited, this will exhibit the same problem (not apparently finishing).    The reason is actually the termination condition of the loop - `std::cin >> temp` will only terminate the loop if end of file or some other error is encountered in the stream.

So, if you type

```
  The cow jumped over the moon
```

`std::cin` will continue to wait for input.   It is generally necessary for the USER to trigger and end of file condition.     Under windows, this requires the user to enter `CTRL-Z` on an empty line followed by the enter key.

An alternative would be to have some pre-agreed text that cause the loop to exit, such as

```
 #include <vector>    // for std::vector
 #include <string>    // for std::string
 #include <iostream>   // std::cout and other I/O facilities

 int main()
 {
      std::vector<std::string> words;
      for(std::string temp; std::cin >> temp && temp != "zzz"; )
           words.push_back(temp);
      std::cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << '\n';
 }
```

which will cause the program to exit when the input contains the word `zzz`.  For example

```
 The cow jumped over the moon  zzz
```

There are other techniques, such as reading one character at a time, and stopping when the user enters two consecutive newlines.   That requires your code to interpret every character, and decide what constitutes a word.   I'll leave that as an exercise.

Note there is no means in standard C++ to directly read keystrokes - the problems above are related to how standard streams work, and interact with the host system.

The user can also use the program "as is" by placing the same text into an actual file, and (when the program is run) redirect input for your program to come from that file.  For example  `your_executable < filename`.

Comment: Thank you. But why did it worked here? https://wandbox.org/permlink/GYEiNuoMGABLZJpD . I mean, there's nothing signaling that specific behaviour. At least, I can't see anything.

Comment: When using a remote site like that, browser feeds input to a server.  The server is probably doing such redirection as I describe.

Comment: *"since they will have good reason to assume your code uses Microsoft-specific extensions, which will mean they probably can't help you."* Typical FUD promulgated by ignorant people. This may be an advantage, in that it discourages unhelpful people from trying to help you. Of course it isn't *necessary* to use precompiled headers, but that doesn't make it a mistake. Plenty of other compilers have a similar facility. Just because you aren't familiar with how it works doesn't mean it is useless. Digressions like this make an otherwise useful answer into something I have trouble upvoting.

Comment: @CodyGray - frankly, it doesn't bother me whether you upvote this answer or not. People are more likely to move past a question if it includes a feature specific to a compiler they do not use, since they are less likely to be able to help. So, if one wants to maximise chances of getting useful help with a question about standard C++ (as in this case) it is better to remove compiler-specific features, unless the question is specifically about such features - which is not the case with this question.

Comment: The "on-topic" part of this answer is actually much more useful than the accepted answer, since it explains what happens and why and how to fix/work around it.

Comment: *"will not work with non-Microsoft compilers"* => you're saying non-MS compilers cannot handle a regular header file (whose default content is empty besides a `#pragma once` directive)? Because it's only handled specially by the compiler if you enable precompiled headers (and by specially, I mean the compiler will simply *require* you to include this as the first thing in the translation unit). Everything else is standard behavior. FUD indeed.

Comment: `stdafx` is not maintained.  It's just the precompiled header for VS to speed up compilation times.  It won't contain "Windows specific headers" unless you put them there.